# Hibernate session persisting between requests

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-tomee

I'm working on a system where things can and will change outside of JPA, so I need a new session for every request, but my JavaEE app deployed into TomEE persists sessions between requests, resulting in entities that are cached when they've since been updated somewhere outside of the app.

I attempted to create a cfg.xml and get the session factory that way, but was just met with exceptions. I also attempted to unwrap the entity manager class to get the factory that way, but got an exception saying the class couldn't be unwrapped. I feel like this may be something to do with how TomEE and Hibernate interact. Are there issues with my current setup. Or am I trying to implement session-per-request wrong,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have is not with the session, it is related with the session cache, so what you can do is invalidate your session cache:

```
session.refresh(entity)
```

then hibernate will compare database data and entity object data if there are differences then it will execute again an sql query.

```
session.clear()
```

will remove everything from the session cache, so you will not get old data.